# VS 2013 Code Analysis results differ when run from IDE and MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Has anyone seen this?  I add Code Analysis to all of the projects in a solution, for all configurations, using the Microsoft Extended Design Guidelines.

In the IDE I get a clean result, in MSBuild I get some CA1034 for the use of nested enum types.

Somewhere along the line it seems like a different set of rules is used between the two environments.

Comment: Are you building one in debug and one in release?

Comment: Pretty sure i'm not.  Are the rules different for each or interpreted differently?

Comment: Which version of MsBuild are you execting? The one in `Program Files` or the one in `%windir%\Microsoft.NET`? Are you specifying an explicit `ToolsVersion` on the MsBuild commandline?

Comment: The rules are not interpreted differently between Debug and Release, but since the rules work on the IL code (the compiled binary), the Release build may have higher optimization levels which cause the binary to be sufficiently different. This can cause rules to either trigger or not trigger depending on the compilation mode.

Comment: I'll check the toolsversion

Comment: Did you figures this one out yet? For me I only get the errors when I've set the build with "/t:Clean,Build". For "/t:Build" it works fine.

Comment: No, we ended up turning it off due to time limitations and only run it manually.